# Python 3.6: Accumulate sklearn nGram by document instead of term

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am new with Python, but I could not find the answer to this anywhere (at least not in a form simple enough for me). How do I accumulate nGram frequencies by document instead of term?

I am creating nGrams based on a description field using sklearn.feature_extraction.text CountVectorizer. Here is the code:

```
df = pandas.read_sql('select unique_id, short_description')
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3,3), analyzer='word') 
X = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['short_description'])   
frequencies = sum(X).toarray()[0]  
results = pandas.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
```

This code provides a results dataframe that consists of one column of nGrams and one column of their frequencies across all records (documents) brought in during the first step.

```
"the quick brown"    4
"quick brown fox"    2
"brown fox jumped"   5
```

Instead of this, I would like the frequency of each nGram for each record:

```
0001    "the quick brown"    2
0001    "quick brown fox"    2
0002    "the quick brown"    2
0002    "brown fox jumped"   5
```

This would allow comparison of documents, as well as comparison of nGrams over time. Logically, this will require somehow mapping the frequencies back to the unique_id that was brought in. I have attempted various ways of appending the frequencies to the original dataframe with no success.

Thank you for any insight you all can provide, and please let me know if I can answer any questions.

**EDIT:**
Here is my latest attempt to accomplish my stated issue per the comments from JD Long below:

I have a dataframe (let's assume only one record for simplicity):

```
id    short_description
0001  the farmer plants grain
0002  the fisher catches tuna
0002  the police officer fights crime
```

Here is the code I'm using to find the nGrams of the short_description field:

```
df = pandas.read_sql('select id, short_description') 
df_grouped = df.groupby('id')

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3,3), analyzer='word')
for id, group in df_grouped:
   X = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(group['short_description'])
   frequencies = sum(X).toarray()[0]
   results = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
   dfinner = pd.DataFrame(word_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

This results is the nGrams being assigned to a dataframe with the id no longer assigned to each nGram:

```
The farmer plants
farmer plants grain
the fisher catches
fisher catches tuna
the police officer
police officer fights
```

How do I then get the id assigned to each nGram? Desired output:

```
id    nGram
0001  The farmer plants
0001  farmer plants grain
0002  The fisher catches
0002  fisher catches tuna
0002  The police officer
0002  police officer fights
0002  officer fights crime
```

Comment: is `unique_id` the document ID? if not, which field tells us which document the text is from?

Comment: yes, unique_id is the document ID (i.e. 0001, 0002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a handful of ways to skin this cat. The ones that come to mind are the following:

1. first request a list of all the unique unique_id records from the db. Read that into a list then iterate over that list doing your DB request on a specific unique_id then do your ngrams and then push the results into a dataframe along with the unique_id... then iterate to the next unique_id
2. Read everything into a dataframe (like you are currently doing) then use the pandas `group_by()` function to group on unique_id and apply your ngram to each group.

Let your data volume be your guide. I think you are small enough volume that #2 should work just fine. Since I don't have your data I can't really test this, but it would look something like:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('unique_id')

# iterate through the groups
for id, group in df_grouped:
  X = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(group['short_description'])   
  frequencies = sum(X).toarray()[0]  
  results = pandas.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency']) 
  ## right here you need to pop your results into a collection of some kind
  ## you can likely put them in a pandas dataframe but I can't guess the 
  ## format of the results... remember that id holds your unique_id for the 
  ## group so you'll want that and the results in your output df
```

Comment: thank you very much - the logic of that loop makes sense. the results are already in a dataframe, so how would you add the results to df_grouped? i tried `df_grouped.insert`, but that can't be used by groupby objects.

Comment: I would create a df inside the loop. In that df put all the ngrams first, then add a column that is the unique_id. Then after that's created append it to the big df where you are accumulating your results: `df_big = df_big.append(df_inner)`

Comment: apologies - it'll take me a while to work through how to do that. thank you for the help, though - wish I had the reputation to vote for your answer

Comment: 'df_inner = pd.DataFrame(word_vectorizer.get_feature_names())' works to get the nGrams into a df. then when I run 'df_inner = df_inner.insert(0, "unique_id", df['unique_id'])' (or any insert for that matter), a list of "None" is returned (10 "None"s for 10 unique_ids). trying to insert a df_grouped column results in a "Length of values does not match length of index" error.

Comment: to get into that level of detail you'll need to provide an example with some dummy data included. It's hard for me to guess what's going on with your objects in your code which I cannot run.

Comment: I realize it took me forever to update to my latest point (which is exactly where I was two months ago, but feel free to check out my edit, @JD_Long